# How to change the indention of references in beamer?

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I am writing my Ph.D. viva presentation using the UTM beamer template which can be obtained from the following link:

https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/skudai-a-beamer-theme-for-universiti-teknologi-malaysia/vcgrnsgxqdrj

My working code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}
\usetheme{Skudai}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet,enumerate,harvard}
\citationstyle{dcu}

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}

\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{definition}[numbered]

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\normalsize}

\title{JORDAN-CHEVALLEY DECOMPOSITION\\ OF RECORDED EEG SIGNALS DURING \\EPILEPTIC SEIZURES}
\author{\footnotesize Candidate: \\
    AMIRUL AIZAD BIN AHMAD FUAD\\
    PCS163035}
\date{\scriptsize \today}
\institute{%
    \sc{Supervised by: Prof. Dr. Tahir Ahmad }\\
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \textit{\scriptsize Department of Mathematical Sciences, Faculty of Science,\\ Universiti Teknologi Malaysia}
}
%\institute{}
\AtBeginSection
{\begin{frame}{Research Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[t]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Krohn-Rhodes decomposition of EEG signals}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Literature Review}
    \framesubtitle{Krohn-Rhodes decomposition of EEG signals}
    \begin{theorem}<1>
        \textup{\cite{Binjadhnan2011}} Any invertible square matrix of EEG-signal readings during an epileptic seizure at time $t$ can be written as a product of elementary EEG signals during an epileptic seizure in one and only one way.
        \label{theorem:unique-factorization}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{exampleblock}{In other words,}<2->
        \begin{equation}
            M_{n\times n}=[U][D]
        \end{equation}
    \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{References}
    \scriptsize
    \bibliographystyle{UTMa}
    \bibliography{amiruldatabase}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

that produces reference's frame as follows:

[image]

How can I fix the problem (red box)? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar problem appears when applying `\bibliographystyle{dcu}` from the `harvard` style. (`\bibliographystyle{UTMa}`  is not included in the Overleaf link.)

I tried (with some  bib entries added ) the style `plain`, `ieeetr` and `apalike`.  None produced what you observe.

[image: j]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[envcountsect]{beamer}
\usetheme{Skudai}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet,enumerate}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{myreferences.bib}

@phdthesis{binjadhnan2011krohn,
    title={Krohn-Rhodes decomposition for electroencephalography signals during epileptic seizure},
    author={Binjadhnan, Faisal Abdurabu Mubarak},
    year={2011},
    school={Universiti Teknologi Malaysia}
}

@book{yang2018optimization,
    title={Optimization Techniques and Applications with Examples},
    author={Yang, Xin-She},
    year={2018},
    publisher={John Wiley~\& Sons},
}

@book{kelley1999iterative,
    title={Iterative methods for optimization},
    author={Kelley, Carl T},
    year={1999},
    publisher={SIAM}
}
@book{cavazzuti2012optimization,
    title={Optimization methods: from theory to design scientific and technological aspects in mechanics},
    author={Cavazzuti, Marco},
    year={2012},
    publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}

@book{grivet2012methodes,
    title={M{\'e}thodes num{\'e}riques appliqu{\'e}es pour le scientifique et l’ing{\'e}nieur (edition 2009): Edition 2013},
    author={Grivet, Jean-Philippe},
    year={2012},
    publisher={EDP sciences}
}       

\end{filecontents}

\bibliographystyle{apalike} % added <<<<

\newcounter{saveenumi}
\newcommand{\seti}{\setcounter{saveenumi}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand{\conti}{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{saveenumi}}}

\resetcounteronoverlays{saveenumi}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{definition}[numbered]

\setbeamerfont{title}{size=\normalsize}

\title{JORDAN-CHEVALLEY DECOMPOSITION\\ OF RECORDED EEG SIGNALS DURING \\EPILEPTIC SEIZURES}
\author{\footnotesize Candidate: \\
    AMIRUL AIZAD BIN AHMAD FUAD\\
    PCS163035}
\date{\scriptsize \today}
\institute{%
    \sc{Supervised by: Prof. Dr. Tahir Ahmad }\\
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    \textit{\scriptsize Department of Mathematical Sciences, Faculty of Science,\\ Universiti Teknologi Malaysia}
}
%\institute{}
\AtBeginSection
{\begin{frame}{Research Outline}
        \tableofcontents[currentsection,hideothersubsections]
\end{frame}}

\begin{document}
    
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{frame}[t]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Krohn-Rhodes decomposition of EEG signals}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Literature Review}
    \framesubtitle{Krohn-Rhodes decomposition of EEG signals}
    \begin{theorem}<1>
        \textup{\cite{binjadhnan2011krohn}} Any invertible square matrix of EEG-signal readings during an epileptic seizure at time $t$ can be written as a product of elementary EEG signals during an epileptic seizure in one and only one way.
        \label{theorem:unique-factorization}
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{exampleblock}{In other words,}<2->
        \begin{equation}
            M_{n\times n}=[U][D]
        \end{equation}
    \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{References}
    \scriptsize
    \nocite{*}  

    %%  \bibliographystyle{dcu} % WRONG result
    
    \bibliography{myreferences} %<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<changed
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```